# I am getting "to" as an answer from Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When i try to send a notification with postman by firebase, I am receiving "to" as an answer and no notification is pushed to my phone.

When I try to send notification throw the firebase console I get the notifications.

Here is my payload :

```
{
    "data": {
        "body" : "hello!",
        "title": "push",
        "click_action":"message"
     },

    "priority": "high"
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: At first glance you seem to be missing a `to` property, which would indicate where to send the message to.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen : That s what I am guessing. But I dont know what to put inside: to.

Comment: That depends on where you want to send the message. You'll usually put the equivalent in there of what you did in the console: one of more device tokens.